# Trying to include Zxing barcode scanner library into my Android project modifying the intent name

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing

I am trying to read custom qr codes with my app using Zxing.
I have added the library to my code. Now I can call the Zxing scan intent and it starts the camera, reads the qr code.

But I also want to change the intent string to prevent conflict with the original Barcode scanner app installed on the phone.

So I changed the intent filter in manifest file as:

```
from:
<action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
to:
<action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCANX"/>
```

And from my activity I call :

```
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "test1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCANX");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
```

However, it stays at the result page with options like "share via email", "share via sms" , "search" etc. I don't want to see this page, I want to get the code directly to the result.

And if I restore the intent string back to original:

```
<action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
```

it works.

But I really want to prevent conflict and the necessity for user to choose scanning app. How can I achieve this ?

thanks.